# Performing Clean Verify Hibernate is unable to find column with logical name

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Suppose I have the following model:

```
class A implements Serializable {
  @Id
  private Integer id;

  @ManyToOne(optional = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "id_b")
  private B b;

}

class B implements Serializable {
  @Id
  private Integer id;

}

class C implements Serializable {
  @Id
  private Integer id;

  @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "id_a", referencedColumnName = "id")
  @JoinColumn(name = "id_bb", referencedColumnName = "id_b")
  private A a;

}
```

Now, conceptually I have a similar (more complex) model that works perfectly with various DBs. Everything works fine! I just have one problem that is literally driving me crazy:

1 If I run `Maven Test` everything goes fine, the tests run and the app build..

2 If I run `clean verify` *skipping tests* everything goes fine..

3 If I run `clean verify` without skipping tests I obtain the follow error:

```
Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource 
[org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation 
of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find 
column with logical name: id_b in A
```

---

if I reverse the order from:

```
@ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "id_a", referencedColumnName = "id")
@JoinColumn(name = "id_bb", referencedColumnName = "id_b")
private A a;
```

to:

```
@ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "id_bb", referencedColumnName = "id_b")
@JoinColumn(name = "id_a", referencedColumnName = "id")
private A a;
```

The mapping error disappear, But the application doesn't work as expected when I use this instances..

Comment: I don't think it's a matter of plugin verification step, but Hibernate initialization. I could reproduce the error while deploying a Jakarta EE webapp with the same entities setting over a Wildfly 27.0.1 server (org.hibernate@6.1.5.Final). Now, about the error you're facing, I spent a while reading the [specification](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/3.1/jakarta-persistence-spec-3.1.html#joincolumns-annotation) and didn't find nothing wrong. I mean, the spec suggests that the use of `@JoinColumns` are necessary for a group of `@JoinColumn`, but the error still occurs.